# java.lang.NullPointerException while doing sentimental analysis with stanford-nlp API

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am new to stanford-nlp API. I am trying to just sentimental analysis with stanford API but it's throwing exception. please see the below logs.

```
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.4 sec].
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator ner
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [5.3 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [2.3 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [4.7 sec].
Adding annotator parse
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [1.1 sec].
Adding annotator dcoref
Adding annotator sentiment
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ejml/simple/SimpleBase
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.SentimentAnnotator.<init>    (SentimentAnnotator.java:48)
    at  edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$14.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:850)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:81)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:262)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:129)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:125)
    at io.stanford.NLP.findSentiment(NLP.java:30)
    at io.stanford.TestStanford.main(TestStanford.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ejml.simple.SimpleBase
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the code that produces this output? My strong suspicion is that you have not included the "sentiment" annotator in your annotators list, either in the properties file you are using to run the code, or the properties object you have passed into the annotation pipeline. Without running the sentiment annotator, the document will not have the sentiment annotations attached, and will therefore null pointer when trying to retrieve them.

Comment: Thanks Gabor. "sentiment" annotator was missing. I added this but now i have another exception. Please see the edited question. Thanks is advance

Answer (score 2):

With the Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.2 distribution there should be a .jar file called ejml-0.23.jar which contains the missing class ; make sure to put this jar in your classpath, in fact you probably want all of the jars that come with Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.2 in your classpath!